Solving $-8\cos^2(A) + 7\sin(2A) -4 = 0$
I'm currently facing following problem in trigonometry:
$$
-8\cos^2(A) + 7\sin(2A) -4 = 0
$$
which is to be solved for $0\le A \le \tau$. The issue for me is that since I have two different terms $\cos$ and $\sin$, I unfortunately don't know how to continue.
I have considered transforming $-8\cos^2(A)$ to $\sin$ by applying the identity $\cos^2(A) = 1 - \sin^2(A)$.
What I then get is $-8+8\sin^2(A) + 7\sin(2A) -4 = 0$, but here I now have $\sin^2(A)$ and $\sin(2A)$, so still unlike terms.
I appreciate your help!

Personally I would have changed the $2\cos^2 A$ into $\cos 2A$ etc. You need to edit this so that the mathematics is properly rendered.

Use double angle identities, you will end up with $7 \sin z - 4 \cos z$ or something similar

As commented, $$7 \sin (2 A)-8 \cos ^2(A)=7 \sin (2 A)-4 \cos (2 A)-4$$ Let $A=\tan^{-1}(x)$ to face a quadratic equation in $x$ which has very simple roots. Do not forget the modulo.

When $\tan(x)=t$ we have $\cos(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$ and $\sin(x)=\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$. It follows
$$-8\cos^2(x)+14\sin(x)\cos(x)-4=0\iff-8\frac{1}{1+t^2}+14\frac{t}{1+t^2}-4=0$$ then when $1+t^2\ne0$ the equation in $t$ becomes $$4t^2-14t+12=0\implies t_1=1.5 \text{ and } t_2=2$$ whose solutions are in radiands, taking inverse functions $\arctan$
$$x_1=0.982793723247\\x_2=1.10714871779$$It remains to keep into account the magnitude of $\tau$.

Excellent solution, thank you sir!

BTW τ is suppossed to refer to TAU which, in our case, is considered = 2PI.

@The SkyRider: You are welcome. Impossible to guess that  $\tau$ is $2\pi$

I initially wrote TAU but then I was prompted to re-format the question and the word "TAU" was replaced with this symbol.

@The Sky Rider: Good because that symbol is just the greek letter tau.

Since $\cos 2x = 2\cos^2 x-1$, we change the problem into:
$$-4\cos2A + 7\sin2A  = 8$$
$$\sqrt{65}(\frac{-4}{\sqrt{65}}\cos2A+\frac{7}{\sqrt{65}}\sin2A) = 8$$
Let $\sin B = \frac{-4}{\sqrt{65}}$, $\cos B = \frac{7}{\sqrt{65}}$; then
$$\sin B \cos2A+\cos B \sin2A = \sin(B+2A) = \frac{8}{\sqrt{65}}$$
then you can solve for A, depending on what $\tau$ is in your problem.
